# How do I install Debian offline?

Tags: debian, system-installation, debian-installer

I'm trying to install Debian 11 on a computer without an internet connection.

According to the [Debian website](https://www.debian.org/CD/http-ftp/):

> To install Debian on a machine without an Internet connection, it's
> possible to use CD images (700 MB each) or DVD images (4.7 GB each).

So officially, it's possible.

However, when I try, as you can see from the two attached screen photos, it asks to set up a network and doesn't give me an option to skip it. It seems that the installation won't progress unless I connect to a network.

I notice that this is completely different from all of the online guides such as [this one](https://computingforgeeks.com/install-debian-11-bullseye-step-by-step-with-screenshots/). In these guides the installer goes from "Configure the keyboard" to entering a hostname. For me, it goes from "Configure the keyboard" to "[!!] Configure the network".

[The Debian installation documentation](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/ch06s03.en.html#di-setup) doesn't consider the possibility that there is no network to connect to during installation.

The problem occurs irrespective of whether I use the text or graphical installer.

How do I proceed?

[image: (photo 1)][image: (photo 2)]

Comment: In the graphical installer of `debian-live-11.0.0-amd64-standard.iso`, after some vain attempts to connect without any physical connection I get the option "Do not configure the network at this time" ... and "Continue without a mirror" and it was possible to finish the installation. The installed system boots and runs well (but the network must be set up without help from the installer).

Comment: I guess it's not common enough to install without network. To have "uncommon" options, find the menu that allows to change the priority of questions, to low: more questions are asked, and maybe then there's a way to skip the network part

Answer (score -1):

you get that menu when you don't select graphical install.
i suggest you use graphical install, you will be able to skip it (you click next and by default when there is no internet connection. you will get the menu and you can pass to the next step)
note. you could get some error.
since yesterday i keep trying to install Debian .
you can install ParallelDisktop and get the Debian for free (the app won't give you the iso but it will install and download Deabian for you)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).